# Input allow numbers and only one letter/symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input which I want to put a bar code using an scanner (bar code contains only numbers) the problem is that maybe I want to scan a bar code more than once, in this case I want to be able to do something like this:

> 10*bar code number

Right now I'm able to allow only numbers in my input with this code:

```
<input name="number" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')">
```

But with this I'm only able to type numbers, what can I do to allow type a determinate letter/symbol in this case: *

In other words I want a Regex that allows numbers and only this symbol " * ". I tried doing something like this:

```
if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/^[0-9*]+$/,'')"
```

But this only allows letters and symbols.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `10*bar code number`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Good point, instead of scan 10 times a bar code I want to allow to type the quantity of times that I want that bar code (in this case 10) and with * knows that I need that bar code n times. For example 3*15000 in this case I want to use 15000 3 times.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you have two separate inputs. One for the barcode itself, the other for the quantity of them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That could be a solution but that's not exactly what I want, maybe I need a Regex that allows only " * " but I don't know how to do that!

Comment: Please clarify your question a little more.

Comment: @asmmahmud Ready, I added exactly what I want and an example of what I have right now... Just a regex that allows numbers and this symbol: *

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you should work on char validation and on input value.

The regular expression help validating just the final input, but to do a better job you should avid all not valid input on *keyDown* event.

And validate the whole input on the *keyUp* value.

Consider this example:

```js
function onKeyDown(event) {
 if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 || event.keyCode == 16 || event.keyCode == 8)
   return true;

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
 var value = event.target.value
  if (!value.match(/^[0-9]+\*?[0-9]*$/)) {
   event.preventDefault();
    event.target.value = value.substring(0, value.length-1);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.getElementById('inputSource').addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
document.getElementById('inputSource').addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
```

```html
My input sample: <input type="text" value="" id="inputSource"/>
```